# Работа со строками Java

Tags: java, алгоритм, строки

Как правильно обработать строку типа:

> 2+8*10-18 (2+14)/2+10 a=2 b=4 10-a*b-4

чтоб получилось

> 2+8*10-18 (2+14)/2+10 10-2*4-4

То есть мы значения переменных a и b поставили на свои места, а выражения a=2, и b=4 удалили из строки.

Вся фишка в универсальности, чтоб независимо от того какие будут переменные или сколько их будет в строке, код работал правильно.

Comment: добавьте ваш вариант

Comment: Могут ли быть переменные в выражении до их инициализации в строке?

Comment: Пожалуйста, не публикуйте благодарность как ответ. Вместо этого проголосуйте за него, если он оказался полезным. Также вы можете выбрать один из ответов в качестве решения вопроса (поставив ему галку).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Токенизация
   Необходимо разбить строку на выражения. Split по пробелам.
2. Итерирование
   Запускаем цикл по выражениям с целью анализа
3. Анализ
   Если выражение имеет вид `^(\w+)=(.*)$`, запоминаем ключ-значение в HashMap
   Переходим к следующей итерации цикла. `continue;`
4. Преобразование
   Производим замену по всем имеющимся в HashMap на данный момент парам.
5. Вывод
   Добавляем преобразованную строку к результату.

Answer (score 0):

Можно двигаться примерно в таком направлении...
Циклы внутри главного метода - плохое решение, посему рефакторинг за вами

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String source = "2+8*10-18 (2+14)/2+10 a=2 b=4 10-a*b-4";

        List <String> substrings = Arrays.stream(source.trim().split(" ")).collect(Collectors.toList());

        Map<String, Integer> varMap = createVarMap(substrings);

        for (int i = 0; i < substrings.size(); i++) {
            for (String var : varMap.keySet()) {
                substrings.set(i, substrings.get(i).replace(var, String.valueOf(varMap.get(var))));
            }
        }

        String result = substrings.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" "));

        System.out.println(result);

        }

        private static Map<String, Integer> createVarMap (List <String> substrings){
            final Map<String,Integer> varMap = new HashMap<>();
            Iterator <String> i = substrings.iterator();
            while(i.hasNext()){
                String substring = i.next();
                String [] result = substring.split("=");
                if (result.length==2) {
                    varMap.put(result[0].trim(), Integer.valueOf(result[1].trim().replace(",", ".")));
                    i.remove();
                }        
            }
            return varMap;
        }    

}
```